# Command script to know if remote Windows server is using PowerShell by default or CDOS

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008, remote

I have a project to connect to a remote Windows server and run a Powershell script.

Is there any command I can run on the remote machine to know whether it was configured with PowerShell by default, so that I can run my script directly using PowerShell rather than CDOS?

This command can be run either in PowerShell or CDOS.

Comment: "now if the remote server was configured in powershell" - What do you mean by this exactly?  Are you using if you can tell if PowerShell was installed on Windows Server 2008?

Answer (score 1):

Your question would indicate you are very new to PowerShell, or at minimum PSRemoting. SO, please spend the time getting up to speed on the topic by using YouTube, MSDN Channel9 and the MS Learning sites, searching for Beginning/Intermediate/Advanced PowerShell and specifically PowerShell Remoting, and PowerShell using SSH.

If you do not get an error when you try and use any PowewrShell command on the remote host, then it's on. Just because it's enabled, does not always mean it's available to you. Many PSRemoting commands require you to be using an account that is in the target host local administrators group.

How to check if a local or remote target has PSRemoting enabled is a common thing, there cmdlets for such checks...

Example(s):

```
Get-Command -Name '*pssession*' | Format-Table -AutoSize

CommandType Name                                  Version Source                      
----------- ----                                  ------- ------                      
Cmdlet      Connect-PSSession                     3.0.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Core   
Cmdlet      Disable-PSSessionConfiguration        3.0.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Core   
Cmdlet      Disconnect-PSSession                  3.0.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Core   
Cmdlet      Enable-PSSessionConfiguration         3.0.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Core   
Cmdlet      Enter-AzureRmWebAppContainerPSSession 5.2.0   AzureRM.Websites            
Cmdlet      Enter-PSSession                       3.0.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Core   
Cmdlet      Exit-PSSession                        3.0.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Core   
Cmdlet      Export-PSSession                      3.1.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility
Cmdlet      Get-PSSession                         3.0.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Core   
Cmdlet      Get-PSSessionCapability               3.0.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Core   
Cmdlet      Get-PSSessionConfiguration            3.0.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Core   
Cmdlet      Import-PSSession                      3.1.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility
Cmdlet      New-AzureRmWebAppContainerPSSession   5.2.0   AzureRM.Websites            
Cmdlet      New-PSSession                         3.0.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Core   
Cmdlet      New-PSSessionConfigurationFile        3.0.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Core   
Cmdlet      New-PSSessionOption                   3.0.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Core   
Cmdlet      Receive-PSSession                     3.0.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Core   
Cmdlet      Register-PSSessionConfiguration       3.0.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Core   
Cmdlet      Remove-PSSession                      3.0.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Core   
Cmdlet      Set-PSSessionConfiguration            3.0.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Core   
Cmdlet      Test-PSSessionConfigurationFile       3.0.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Core   
Cmdlet      Unregister-PSSessionConfiguration     3.0.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Core 


Get-PSSessionConfiguration

# get function / cmdlet details
Get-Command -Name Get-PSSessionConfiguration -Syntax

# Results

Get-PSSessionConfiguration [[-Name] <string[]>] [-Force] [<CommonParameters>]


(Get-Command -Name Get-PSSessionConfiguration).Parameters.Keys

# Results

Name
Force
Verbose
Debug
ErrorAction
WarningAction
InformationAction
ErrorVariable
WarningVariable
InformationVariable
OutVariable
OutBuffer
PipelineVariable

Get-help -Name Get-PSSessionConfiguration -Full
Get-help -Name Get-PSSessionConfiguration -Online

Get-help -Name Get-PSSessionConfiguration -Examples

# Results

Get-PSSessionConfiguration  
Get-PSSessionConfiguration -Name Microsoft* 
Get-PSSessionConfiguration -Name Full | Format-List -Property * 
(Get-PSSessionConfiguration Microsoft.PowerShell.Workflow).PSObject.Properties | Select-Object Name,Value | Sort-Object Name    
dir wsman:\localhost\plugin 
Connect-WSMan -ComputerName Server01    
dir WSMan:\Server01\Plugin  
dir WSMan:\Server01\Plugin\*\Resources\Resource*\Capability | where {$_.Value -eq "Shell"} | foreach {($_.PSPath.split("\"))[3] }   
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Delegate Server02  
Connect-WSMan Server02  
Set-Item WSMan:\Server02*\Service\Auth\CredSSP -Value $true 
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Get-PSSessionConfiguration} -ComputerName Server02 -Authentication CredSSP -Credential Domain01\Admin01    
(Get-PSSessionConfiguration -Name CustomShell).resourceURI
```

... and well documented on TechNet, The MS docs, site, the PowerShell help files, and many blogs and Q&A site all over the web. One just has to do a simple search to find those items and examples.

Search 'validate if psremoting is enable on a remote host'
Example hits:

[How to detect whether powershell remoting is enabled](https://syscloudpro.com/2014/07/26/how-to-detect-whether-powershell-remoting-is-enabled/)

[Enable PowerShell Remoting and check if it’s enabled](https://www.dtonias.com/enable-powershell-remoting-check-enabled/)

Comment: No worries. Glad to assist. If this solves your use case, please mark as you accepted answer for the benefit of folks who come across this.